# Trying to call by Enum (NestJS)

Tags: node.js, enums, nestjs

I'm coding on `NestJS` and I'm trying to call my database info by enumeration.

Example: I want all of motherboard (motherboard is an `enum`). I'm having many options for this.

I would like your opinion and for you, what is the best option?

This is my Entity :

```
    @Entity('component')
export class Component {
    static idComponent(idComponent: any): Component[] | PromiseLike<Component[]> {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    idComponent: number;
    @Column()
    name: string;
    @Column()
    brand: string;
    @Column()
    availability: string;
    @Column()
    price: string;
    @Column('enum', { enum: ComponentType })
    type: ComponentType;
    service_type: ComponentType;

    @Column('datetime', { default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
    date: string;

    @ApiProperty({ enum: () => Configurateur })
    @OneToMany(() => Configurateur, configurateur => configurateur.component)
    ComponentType: Configurateur[];
}
```

My Controller :

```
@ApiTags('component')
@Controller('component')
export class ComponentController {
    constructor(private componentService: ComponentService) { }
    @Get('all')
    async findAll(@Res() res) {
        const lists = await this.componentService.findAll();
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(lists);
    }
    @Get('id')
    async findById(@Res() res, @Query('id') id: string) {
        const lists = await this.componentService.findById(id);
        if (!lists) throw new NotFoundException('Id does not exist!');
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(lists);
    }
    @Get('type')
    async findByType(@Res() res, @Query('type') ComponentType: string) {
        const listsType = await this.componentService.findByType(ComponentType);
        if (!listsType) throw new NotFoundException('Id does not exist!');
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(listsType);
    }
}
```

And my Service :

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ComponentService {
        constructor(
            @InjectRepository(Component)
            private readonly componentRepository: Repository<Component>,
        ) { }
        async findAll(): Promise<Component[]> {
            return await this.componentRepository.find();
        }
        async findById(id): Promise<Component[]> {
            const customer = await this.componentRepository.findByIds(id);
            return customer;
        }
        async findByType(ComponentType): Promise<any> {
            const customerType = await this.componentRepository.find(ComponentType);
            return customerType;
        }
// Have Error and is a test
        getType(ByType): Promise<any> {
            let Type = String(ByType);
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                const type = this.componentRepository.find(type => type.Type === Type);
                if (!type) {
                    throw new HttpException('Course does not exist', 404)
                }
                resolve(Type)
            });
        }
    }
```

Edit : `CompentType` is my `Enums` file.

Thank you for your time.